# String truncation/summarization

Tags: code-golf, string

Not entirely sure if this one or a similar challenge has already been posted, but here it goes anyway.

Write a program that takes a `string` as input and writes its trucated/summarized `output` form such that a specific `sep` (separator) is placed in the middle, removing the necessary characters of the original `string` so that the length of `output` equals a given `width`.

## Rules

- Input is a `string`, a `width` and a `sep` (separator);
- `if len(string) <= width: output = string`, meaning that the output is the string itself unchanged;
- `if width <= len(sep): output = sep`, meaning that the output is the separator only;
- `len(output)` must be equal to `width`, with the exception of the previous case;
- The excess character in case of uneven number of remaining characters for each half of the string can be placed on the left or right halve;
- Standard code-golf challenge with the smallest program to win.

## Examples

Format: `"string" [length(string)] --> "output" [length(ouput) / width]` with `sep` equal to `_(...)_` (`_` are whitespaces).

```
"xtlgxbdwytxcjacu" [16] --> "x (...) " [8 / 8]
"upjptz" [6] --> " (...) " [7 / 3]
"h" [1] --> "h" [1 / 1]
"qsshkvmawcmf" [12] --> " (...) " [7 / 7]
"tvdknroxszhufgck" [16] --> "tv (...) k" [10 / 10]
"ag" [2] --> "ag" [2 / 5]
"vbgdegtgshnzjrudca" [18] --> "vbgd (...) udca" [15 / 15]
"bscwimjjhmgvcwp" [15] --> "bscwimjjhmgvcwp" [15 / 18]
"xwhgbaenornbzwirlp" [18] --> "xwhgbaenornbzwirlp" [18 / 18]
"tbqyrekkzyizc" [13] --> "t (...) " [8 / 8]
"oowdwbeezeh" [11] --> "o (...) h" [9 / 9]
"avlzfzpjazhjc" [13] --> "avlzfzpjazhjc" [13 / 15]
"dngxmebwenfrbidonses" [20] --> "dngxme (...) donses" [19 / 19]
"bqfxyffdemjghipk" [16] --> "bqfxyffdemjghipk" [16 / 16]
"sfwnlkreghzff" [13] --> " (...) " [7 / 5]
"dznlsyaojtferxh" [15] --> "dznlsyaojtferxh" [15 / 17]
"zwkhjdafkzjdgc" [14] --> "zwk (...) dgc" [13 / 13]
"kpzochngmwoulne" [15] --> "kpz (...) lne" [13 / 13]
"vluqvhpcxg" [10] --> "vluqvhpcxg" [10 / 10]
"wuc" [3] --> "wuc" [3 / 8]
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan The latter is correct. The program should accept a string, the desired width and separator.

Comment: The two inequality driven rules have a conflict when len(string) = len(sep) = width, for example, what should the output be for string `ab`, separator `12`, width `2`. Are we free to output either the string or the separator in such cases?

Comment: The input/output need to be strings ? Or they can be list of characters?

Comment: @JonathanAllan The rules are in order. It is preferred to output the string itself if there is room for it. So, in your case, the output should be `ab`.

Comment: @Rod The challenge talks about strings as a sequence of characters, but I guess that lists are good too as it should not affect how the program is designed.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58902/42545)

Comment: The [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] tag is to be used for constant output. I have replaced it with the [tag:string] tag, you can revert if you disagree.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No worries. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>93</s> <s>76</s> 72 bytes

```python
s,w,p=input()
l=len(s)
if w<l:w=max(w-len(p),0);s[-~w/2:l-w/2]=p
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Lcs9CsMwDAXg3acwmmxQ3J@taXySkKGlSTE4rolSlKlXd2Xw8AnxnlQIGbMPKX93Y1X0cU6GrAqL5iH27NfHYbirabZ4tncaux@frn3sZE4@q7yFtGsqZYQXICTxFodYxSyegtte@0VsLQ@i/n1aR@2OYMLLDUEb55zV8Ac)

Input and output are a list of characters

Comment: Your code outputs the wrong value for the "upjptz" example.

Comment: @TomDevs fixed it

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 78 bytes

```
(w,s,e,l=s.length,m=e.length)=>l>w?m<w?s.slice(0,w-m>>1)+e+s.slice(m-w>>1):e:s
```

I was pleasantly surprised to discover that `w-m>>w` and `m-w>>1` give the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 76 bytes

```python
def f(s,p,w):t=len(s);q=len(p)-w;print[s,[p,s[:~q/2]+p+s[t+q/2:]][q<0]][t>w]
```

Tests are at **[TryItOnline!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#dVLLctwgEDx7v4LiJNWSjZ2UnUSO8yMqlUu8hSSEAAmJQ359jSjv3nyBmZ6herqHK2Uc8MIhg0JZ@beB6cKVr3MOTPktvBrbaV87VBvk6ur//P1HczZnV/tzCqumqee/j@n0/0Jz9cx5B95AXcDND2LDNOx@I6olC0S/S1TAxSjjI0Q/j0RC9HTcs3OyX8c2kJFD9OuA/Ep7bafNRblwQfrU@XjgrYDo@QhWLCgTXjipo7ILJW1qyRXsSOhGpeQoVhJMgjPzFqTALdOT1TiGzg73isfzblnfx72L5HPOaQo0YMYiS0P@yczrEHk0qo1SkRsX1WIbGQ5Mc4s7OmnHXKrlB3jm2845ZaMSsjOHhJcDdzzoobdMyMj5pxoa9eD2dlKeM7sdvmQXYuiloi3vo6LiIM229SZORGoxhmkZNLvB67DMqzRkEzezwpLlNCeTdgLfi8vlUr7DE58scAgE0GmQN1adHvKWAey0WXwFESjSlwAmNZXl6YHfk3sjvH6pHUGQmQD8AA)**

*Note:* Places the extra character for odd splits on the right hand side
(question states that either is fine, although the examples show left only).

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, <strike>103</strike> 99 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d=a.length,e=c.length,f=(b>e?b:e)-e,g=a.split(""),h=g.splice(-~f/2,d-f,c))=>b<d?g.join(""):a
```

```js
f=(a,b,c,d=a.length,e=c.length,f=(b>e?b:e)-e,g=a.split(""),h=g.splice(-~f/2,d-f,c))=>b<d?g.join(""):a;

console.log(f("dngxmebwenfrbidonses", 19, " (...) "));
```

Comment: You can save some bytes by changing `("")` into `\`\``. You can also shorten f: `f=b>e?b-e:0`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 90 bytes

```
If[(l=Length)[i=#2]<=#,#2,If[#<=(s=l@#3),#3,Join[(t=i~Take~Floor[#/2]&)[#-s],#3,t[s-#]]]]&
```

Unnamed function taking an integer (the width) as its first argument and two lists of characters (the string and the separator) as its second/third arguments, and returning a list of characters.